# What is the usage and corresponding meaning of אלהים "elohim" in Exodus 20:3?

Tags: exodus

> לא יהיה לך אלהים אחרים על פני׃

(You shall have no other gods before / beside Me.)

"elohim" in Exodus 20:3 is a noun plural in number.  By the context that "other" in Hebrew is also plural to confirm that "elohim" is plural and therefore not a personal proper name that could be singular if referring to one singular entity, is it a common noun about members of a kind of living being, a common noun about objects of worship, a common noun about judges, a common noun about those who are godly, a common noun about those who are mighty, a proper noun of a person, or others?

Answer (score 2):

We have various passages in scripture that assure us that idols are "nothings" which men make out of tree stumps and what not and are as intrinsically insignificant as any other piece of wood or stone:

> CSB Jeremiah 10:8 They are both stupid and foolish, instructed by worthless idols made of wood!

But in other places such as in the Genesis account of the garden YHVH is juxtaposed against a very real rival who in the form of an extremely intelligent and powerful adversary.

In other places we see that God's real enemy, the Satan receives worship by proxy via the "nothings":

> [Lev 17:7 NKJV] 7 "They shall no more offer their sacrifices to demons, after whom they have played the harlot. This shall be a statute forever for them throughout their generations." '
>
> [1Co 10:19-22 NKJV] 19 **What am I saying then? That an idol is anything, or what is offered to idols is anything? 20 Rather, that the things which the Gentiles sacrifice they sacrifice to demons and not to God, and I do not want you to have fellowship with demons**. 21 You cannot drink the cup of the Lord and the cup of demons; you cannot partake of the Lord's table and of the table of demons. 22 Or do we provoke the Lord to jealousy? Are we stronger than He?

Many think that the Satan is referred to in Corinthians as "the god of this world" (which in Hebrew would be the ELOHIM of this world):

> [2Co 4:4 KJV] 4 In whom the god of this world hath blinded the minds of them which believe not, lest the light of the glorious gospel of Christ, who is the image of God, should shine unto them.

There is also a sense in which other nations can be "false gods" in that they can be depended upon to save Israel in their dicey situations:

> [Hos 14:1-3 CSB] 1 Israel, return to the LORD your God, for you have stumbled in your iniquity.  2 Take words of repentance with you and return to the LORD. Say to him: "Forgive all our iniquity and accept what is good, so that we may repay you with praise from our lips.  3 "Assyria will not save us, we will not ride on horses, and we will no longer proclaim, 'Our gods! ' to the work of our hands. For the fatherless receives compassion in you."

So when God says not to have any "elohim" ("gods") before him he means:

- do not regard idols as anything because they are "nothings"
- do not regard idols as anything because they are proxies for devils
- do not listen to the very real enemy, the Satan as he is a liar and a thief
- do not depend on the might of nations but on the LORD

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  So you take "elohim" as a common noun in plural form and means gods all inclusively -- idols that are nonliving things or fallen angels or the might of nations and are being worshiped.  Can it also include the members of the kind of ever-living beings ?

Comment: Rather than viewing the prohibition as referring to a list of forbidden beings (real and imagined) I think it best to take it entirely inclusive and just day, "Don't trust anyone implicitly except Me!".

Comment: I take it only referring to the real Gods (each of them is an ever-living being who is and who was and who will be), excluding non-living idols and their corresponding real objects (anything in the heavens above (angels), the earth below (including human beings), or the waters under the earth) that are covered by the second commandment.  So my translation is "You shall have no three or more other Gods before Me."  "three or more" because "Originally, 3 (Hebrew noun) numbers were indicated, singular (one), dual (two), plural (three or more)." LaSor  Handbook of Biblical Hebrew vol.2, 1979 p.75.

Comment: Why do you take that position?

Comment: It means most sense.  The commandment is about "How many real Gods you should have?"  The value system is the deeper level of a legal system.  Real Gods are most valuable.  Boundary is also a very important accept of a legal system.

Comment: It sounds to me like you might be reading *into* the passage rather than out of it, no?

Comment: Indeed we need to go into the implications of all parts of this legal document which is very precisely constructed and seriously written by the finger of YHWH.

Comment: You say: "Many think that the Satan is referred to in Corinthians as "the god of this world" (which in Hebrew would be the ELOHIM of this world)." I think the singular/plural would be preserved in going from Greek to Hebrew. So the god of this world shpuld be eloah vs elohim.

Comment: @Revelation Lad Perhaps it would be "elah" as in Daniel 2:47 ענה מלכא לדניאל ואמר מן קשט די אלהכון הוא אלה אלהין ומרא מלכין וגלה רזין די יכלת למגלא רזה דנה׃

Comment: @Chin-LeeChan The word in Daniel 2:47 is the Aramaic equivalent to the Hebrew אֱלוֹהַּ so your observation is possible. My point is the Greek is singular θεὸς (god) not plural θεοὶ (gods). In 1 Corinthians 8:5 Paul expresses a similar thought of false **gods** (plural). As he uses both the singular and plural in addressing the same group, I believe the better approach, if one is trying to make a connection to the Hebrew, is to preserve the distinctions in the original texts. Thus, IMO, it is impossible for Paul to be thinking the Elohim of this world is the deceiver.

Comment: @RevelationLad  Thank you for your comment!  Paul was using Theos as the Greek name of God the Father while Moses was using Elohim as the Hebrew name of God the Father because both Moses and Paul were inspired for their word choice.  39 books of Old Testament were sufficient to prove that there are three Gods.  So in the Greek New Testament, the Greeks names for God the Father, God the Son, and God the Holy Spirit are correspondingly Theos, Logos, and Pneuma.

Answer (score 0):

GOD

> "OT words for God.  A cluster of three words, possibly from the same ancient root, are translated "God" of "god" in the NIV and NASB.  These are el, eloah, elohim.   Each is a generic terms, meaning "god" or "mighty one."   Normally when one of these words occur in the OT, it designates either the true God or something the pagan nations viewed as a god.  In only a few instances are these words used of angels or mighty human beings."-'Expository Dictionary of the Bible' by L.O. Richards p.312-313

also

> "El and Elohim are from the earliest times the general names applied to the spirits or demons associated in popular belief with certain localities or natural objects such as trees, wells, rocks, stones, etc.,  Some of these numerous vague spirits attained in the course of time to a more definitely personal quality, advancing as the protective spirits of places and tribes to the stage of deity.   An instructive passage is Gen. 33.20, 'And he [Jacob] erected there an alter and called it El-elohe-Israel'.  El is here no longer a mere appellative, but has  become a proper name, the name of the God of Israel, while at the same time it is the name of the alter itself, closely associated with the stone (cf. Gen. 28.18f) of which the alter consists."-'A Theologial Word Book of the Bible' Ed. by A. Richardson D.D. p.94-94

and further

> “GOD … The names of God . . . As the words ‘el and theos can be used to refer to any supernatural power, of which there may be many, as well as to the supreme or absolute supernatural being.  Because of this, translators of the Bible have felt free to use similar words in other languages which have a corresponding breath of meaning (e.g. ‘God’ in English),  This is in contrast to Islamic translators of the Qur’an, for example, who retain the word ‘Allah as an untranslatable proper name, even thought there is no semantic justification for this.  The Bible’s willingness to use ***generic**** words of deity to refer to the unique God of Israel confirms its assertion that some knowledge of him in innate in every rational creature and that pagan deities are but pale and corrupt reflections of this knowledge.
>   In the Bible God reveals himself by the name YHWH, which is usually vocalized as ‘Yahweh’, but which at some point ceased to be used by the ancient Israelites . . . which has come into English via its Latinized form     ‘Jehovah’.”-‘New Dictionary of Biblical Theology’ published by InterVarsty Press p.513

*”generic  adj. 1 characteristic of or relating to a class; general, not specific or special.  2 Biol. characteristic of or belonging to a genus.  generically adv. [Latin: related to *genus].”-Oxford Dictionary

In simple terms God is God, to the European mind, but not so the case to the Near Eastern mind (the Holy Scriptures where prepared for their culture originally) there is a lot more involved, which we should take into consideration when contemplating the Scriptures, as the above shows,  many things are called God, god, gods etc. in the Bible so having the right prospective (and Scripture context) of this will help us to understand why Jesus can be "a god" (or divine one) and just as true, but with out being The Almighty God.

Humans are referred to as "God" or "god".

> Exodus 4:16  "And he* must speak for you to the people; and it must occur that he will serve as a mouth to you, and you** will serve as God*** to him*."
>   *Aaron; **Moses; ***N.W.T. (ftn) "As God.” Heb., le´•lo•him', pl.; Gr., the•on'; Lat., De'um."
>
> Exodus 7:1   "Consequently Jehovah said to Moses: "See, I have made you God* to Pharaoh, and Aaron     your own brother will become your prophet.
>   *N.W.T. "(ftn.) “God.” Heb., ´elo•him'; Gr., the•on'; Latin, De'um."
>
> N.I.V. Study Bible. Comment on Ex 7:1 (and Ex 4:16).
>   "As God transmits his word through his prophets to his people, so Moses will transmit God's message through Aaron to pharaoh.  The prophet's task was to speak God's word on God's behalf.  He was God's "mouth" (4:15-16)."

Jesus Christ is the prophet ("The Word") for Jehovah, like Moses (and much more), whom was a prophetic picture of The Christ, as Moses was the godlike mediator of the Law Covenant, whereas Jesus is the godlike Mediator (1 Tim 2:5; Heb 12:24) of the New Covenant as Deuteronomy 18:15 reads "A prophet from your own midst, from your brothers, like me, is what Jehovah your God will raise up for you—to him YOU people should listen."  See John 1:45; 6:14; Acts 3:22-23; 7:37.

> Zechariah 12:8   “ . . .and the house of David like God. . .”
>
> On the above ‘A New Commentary On The Holy Scriptures’ by S.P.C.K p.623 says:-
>   “the house of David shall be as God.   The royal house of David will figure as the representative of    the divine leadership (cf. Ex 4 16) in the theocratic state.”
>
> Psalms  82:1-8   "God is stationing himself in the assembly of the Divine One*;  In the middle of the gods** he
>   judges:  "How long will YOU keep on judging with injustice  And showing partiality to the wicked themselves?  Be judges for the lowly one and the fatherless boy. To the afflicted one and the one of little means do  justice.   Provide escape for the lowly one and the poor one;  Out of the hand of the wicked ones deliver [them]."   They have not known, and they do not understand;  In    darkness they keep walking about;  All the  foundations of the earth are made to totter.    "I myself   have said, 'YOU are gods***,  And all of YOU are sons of the Most High. . . ."
>   *N.W.T. (ftn) "Or, “God.” Heb., ´El; LXXVg, “gods”; Sy, “angels.”"
>   **N.W.T. (ftn) "Or, “godlike ones.” Heb., ´elo•him'; LXXVgc, “gods”; Sy, “angels”; T, “judges.”"
>   ***N.W.T. (ftn) "Or, “godlike ones.” Heb., ´elo•him'; Gr., the•oi'; Syr., da´•la•hin; Lat., di'i; T, like   angels.”
>
> N.I.V. Study Bible. Comment on Ps 82:6.
>   "I said.  Those who rule (or judge) do so by God's appointment (see 2:7 ; Isa 44:28) and thus they are his representatives- whether they acknowledge him or not (see Ex 9:16; Jer 27:6; Da 2:21; 4:17.32; 5:18; Jn 17:11; Ro 13:1).  gods. See note on v. 1*. sons of. See note on v, 1, Most High. See note on Ge 14:19."
>   *"An early rabbinic interpretation (see Jn 10:35-35) understanding the "gods" (vv. 1,6) to be unjust rulers and judges in Israel, of whom there were many . . . ."

K.J.V. Companion Bible, Ps 82:1
**"gods  Elohim: used of earthly judges as representing Him.  Cp. Ex. 21.6; 22.8, 9, 28 (quoted in  Acts 23.5.).  Hence Moses is so spoken of (Ex. 7. 1).  (it is used also of idols as representing even a     false god.)  See John 10. 34, 35."

> "Verse 6. Ye are gods — Or, with the prefix of k ke, the particle of similitude, µyhlak keelohim, “like God.” Ye are my representatives, and are clothed with my power and authority to dispense judgment and justice, therefore all of them are said to be children of the Most High."-Clarke's Commentary OT, Vol. 3 Job - Song of Solomon by Adam Clarke p.1084
>
> Psalm 82:6  “I myself have said, ‘YOU are gods, And all of YOU  are sons of the Most High.

It is clear that Jesus is “God’s Son” by his own admission (John 10:36), also God’s (Heb 1:5), and is one of many such, as the Scriptures make clear, excepting he is a very special an "Only-begotten" one, see John 1:14,18.

As God’s “sons” can be also be called “gods” by God himself (as above) and being as Jesus or “The Word,” who is God’s “son” (John 1:14), can then, by context and connection, be correctly referred to as “a god” or one of the many of God’s “sons” called “gods” human or otherwise!

Just a bit of info.

Comment: My definition of a God is that a God is an ever-living intelligent being based on Revelation 1:4 "who is and who was and who will".  Any intelligent being who has this characteristic is a God.  What is your definition of a God?

Comment: The Bible teaches that there is only one Almighty God, that is "Jehovah;" "the Most High" (see K.J.V. Psalm 83:18).

Comment: The word "God", Hebrew or Greek, is a relative term, sometimes it refers to The Almighty and or the various things you pointed out, context shows which is which.   Define Him; ABOVE AND BEYOND ALL!!!  To him the entire cosmos is smaller then this "." full stop. Isa. 40:22  There is One who dwells above the circle of the earth, And its inhabitants are like grasshoppers. He is stretching out the heavens like a fine gauze, And he spreads them out like a tent to dwell in.

Comment: An angel is an angelic spirit of the angel kind.  A human being is a spirit with a body with human DNA or genome.  Angels and human beings all have beginnings of their existence.  Most high position seems valueless if there was only one Being existing before Creation.  So YHWH introduced Himself to Moses to introduce Him as "I AM THAT I AM" about His supreme existence instead of "the Most High".  Please consider adjusting your definition of the God kind of beings..

Comment: @Chin_Lee Chan Paul said : 1 Cor 8:4-6  Now concerning the eating of food offered to idols, we know that an idol is nothing in the world and that there is no God but one. 5 For even though there are so-called gods, whether in heaven or on earth, just as there are many “gods” and many “lords,” 6 there is actually to us one God, the Father, from whom all things are and we for him; and there is one Lord, Jesus Christ, through whom all things are and we through him."  This is the issue for Christians to stand up for and show which God is which?????

Comment: @Chin-Lee Chan  Thia is a better rendering of the Hebrew verbs therein:  Exodus 3:13-15    "But Moses said to the true God: “Suppose I go to the Israelites and say to them, ‘The God of your forefathers has sent me to you,’ and they say to me, ‘What is his name?’ What should I say to them?” 14 So God said to Moses: “I Will Become What I Choose to Become.” And he added: “This is what you are to say to the Israelites, ‘I Will Become has sent me to you.’”

Comment: God is just a supernatural being BUT which is the God of Gods?  Joshua 22:22   “The God of gods, Jehovah! The God of gods, Jehovah!

Comment: Thank you for continue this search for truth and the most appropriate translation of every words from the mouth of Theos!  About God of Gods, I take it as among the three Gods, the Father was worshiped by the other two Gods.  For clarity, GOD of Gods is the Father.  GOD is the God being worshiped.  God is the kind of ever-living being who was and who is and who will.  GOD is the object of being worship.  Two different meanings of the same word.

Comment: @ Chan-Lee Chan  Jehovah is Almighty God.   Jesus, "The Word" (Jehovah's spokesman)  is "a god"  or a divine being like God is a divine being living in the spirit relm of existance.   See N.W.T. John 1:1 & !8.  Holy spirit is not a God it is just pure power from Jehovah.  Jesus like the other angels is one of Jehovah's creations.  See Proverbs 8:22-31 is Jesus, "The Word"  personified as wisdom.

Comment: Thanks! You wrote that "Jesus, "The Word" (Jehovah's spokesman) is "a god" or a divine being like God is a divine being living in the spirit relm of existance."  As a common noun, you define "god" as "a divine being living in the spirit realm of existence".  Is a divine being a being who was and who is and who will be?

Comment: @Chin-Lee Chan  Only Jehovah is from everlasting to everlasting, ALL other beings are his creations, spirit or human, animal etc. etc.

Comment: To you only Jehovah is a divine being, isn't He?  There is only one god = divine being.  There is no other god = divine being.  Then god of gods is not possible without a group of at least three gods, since god of gods means the best god or the object of worship of gods.  Similar to king of kings, it means the ruler of rulers or the best ruler among rulers.

Comment: @Chin-Lee han  First God is not a Trinity, that is a pagan greft on to the Bible from around 300 C.E. by the Pagan Constantine.  In Greek "Theos" can be applied to spirit beings (e.g.. Angels or Demons), lifless objects, & Human beings according to context.   The same with "Elohim."     Angels are supernatural divine beings.   Jesus in Heaven is a supernatural divine being.   In Psalm 82 humans are called "gods" verse 6.  So at best "Theos" and "Elohim" are relative Generic terms which can only be understood correctly by examining the context of usage in The Bible!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86168/discussion-between-ethos-and-chin-lee-chan).

Comment: Sorry that I cannot accept your invitation to seek the truth offline into chat because the truth need to be like light for the world to see more clearly.

Comment: I was a former Trinitarian but I am leaning toward being a Tritheist -- three God, one Godhead.  I need to firmly based my leaning in the Hebrew Old Testament and the Greek New Testament.  It is a very important base is the first commandment which can be translated as "You shall have no three or more other Elohim before me."  The implication is that you shall have two more other Elohim (ever-living intelligent beings) before YHWH that makes three ever-living intelligent beings in total. In another words, we should have 3 ever-living Beings who are qualified to be worshiped as Gods.

Comment: @Chin-Lee Chan 1st The chat room here can be for all to see if I undedrstand right?

Comment: @ Chin-Lee Chan  The Hebrew did not have a Trinity; they were strict Monotheists, that is one Almighty God:  Deut. 6:4   “Listen, O Israel: Jehovah (YHWH) our God is one Jehovah.  Jesus thought the same:  Mark 12:29  ".Jesus answered: “The first is, ‘Hear, O Israel, Jehovah (YHWH)our God is one Jehovah."   quoting from Deut 6:4  so Christian do not follow The Trinity as it is not from The Bible.  Paul taught the same:  1 Corinthians 8:6  " . . .there is actually to us one God, the Father,"

Comment: Deuteronomy 6:4 in LXX "...Κύριος ὁ θεὸς ἡμῶν Κύριος εἷς ἐστιν·"  Mark 12:29 in Greek "...κύριος ὁ θεὸς ἡμῶν κύριος εἷς ἐστίν"  Mark here is a direct quote of LXX.  The key is on the words "ὁ θεὸς" and "εἷς".  "ὁ θεὸς" is a personal proper noun because "elohim" in Deuteronomy is also a personal proper noun.  "εἷς" means "integral of making promise and fulfilling the promise"      This understanding is consistent to one of its possible meaning "in opposed to a division into parts, and in ethical matters to dissensions: " (Thayer's Greek Lexicon, STRONGS NT 1520: εἷς)

Comment: @Chin-Lee Chan Jesus is quoting from the Hebrew not the Greek as he would not follow the false pratice of substituting "YHWH" for "Adoni" or "Kurios" by the scribes whom he condemed for not following the scriptures beside, The LXX retained "YHWH" in Hebrew lettering among the Greek text.  Go To -  https://www.ibiblio.org/bgreek/test-archives/html4/1996-03/12555.html      See Matthew 6:9.

Comment: https://www.ibiblio.org/bgreek/test-archives/html4/1996-03/12559.html In Romans 10  Jesus was referred as YHWH.  It is clear that in the Old Testament God the Father was referred as YHWH.  If it was a personal name, it would be used to refer to both Jesus and God the Father with using Sr. or Jr.  However if YHWH is a title than it can be used to apply to either one of them to indicate that whoever was having the title was serving accordingly.  So I still think that YHWH is a tittle and not a personal proper name.

Comment: @Chi-Lee Chan If that is the case you disregard Scripture. Jehovah had his son on earth named "Jesus" : Matt  1:21  "She will give birth to a son, and you are to NAME him Jesus. : Psalm 83:18 "May people know that you, whose NAME is Jehovah (Heb, YHWH), You alone are the Most High over all the earth. : Exodus 6:3 "my NAME Jehovah  (Heb. YHWH) . . .

Comment: Have you been able to rule out "sham", the Hebrew word for "name", that it also means "title"?

Comment: @Chin=Lee Chan  I only except what The Scriptures state!

Comment: Hallelujah!  The Scriptures were written in Hebrew and Aramaic and Greek.  The translation of the Scriptures is simply a translation which is not infallible and free from inaccuracy.  So the translation of the Hebrew word "שֵׁם" can be translated as "title" depending on context, even though no one is doing it this way yet.  https://biblehub.com/hebrew/8034.htm

Comment: @Chin-Lee Chan  Hallelujah, Good word, means "Praise Jehovah."  That is as maybe.   So when asked the "name" of the God you worship what do you say?

Comment: I would say, "Elohim, Elohim Et, and Ruah Elohim in Hebrew.  Theos, Logos, and Pneuma in Greek."

Comment: @Chin-Lee Chan Paul said at Romans 10:13 "Everyone for who will call the Name of Jehovah shall have life." (Luke penned the same therein at Acts 2:21) From 'The Peshitta Aramaic-English Interlinear New Testament.'   So it would seem you are at odds with them because the name of their God is "Jehovah"; why?

Comment: @Chin-Lee Chan  I feel you have missed the point of what God said here: Isaiah 42:8  "I am Jehovah (YHWH) . That is MY NAME ..."   Note in this succinct there is NO "El" or "Elohim" or "Rush Elohim" etc. etc. ONLY "YHWH" for His name"

Comment: I have been questioning that the Hebrew word that has been translated as "name".  What prevents it to be translated as "title"?